# Removing elements from a list based on indices in another list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list `J`. I want to remove specific elements from `J[0]` based on `index`. For example, I want to remove `J[0],J[3]` based on elements in `index`. But I am getting an error. I present the expected output.

```
J=[[2, 6, 9, 10]]

index=[[0,3]]

for i in range(0,len(J)):
    for k in range(0,len(index)): 
        J[i].remove(index[k][0])
print(J)
```

The error is

```
 in <module>
    J[i].remove(index[k][0])

ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

The expected output is

```
[6,9]
```

Comment: Do you really have _nested_ lists?

Comment: `remove()` method remove the first occurrence of a specified element from a list. you have specify the index not the element value!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try list comprehension / filtering (and fix the `[0]` as required):

```
new_J = [j for i,j in enumerate(J[0]) if i not in index[0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well in this code you loop your code only 1 time for j and index because both len(j) and len(index) is 1.

Try this:

```
J=[2, 6, 9, 10]

index=[0,3]

for i in range(len(index)):
    J.pop(index[i] - i)

print(J)
```